# Fill in a character on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios8

What is the best way to fill in a character on iOS such as this one ⇧. I'd like to keep it a character because it is easily scalable and adaptable to different sizes. I can change the color of the outside easily because it is a character but inside is a bit more tricky.

Comment: You may be better off redrawing it in something like [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com), so that you have complete control over the appearance. I don’t know how to fill a text character either, but I imagine it’s probably more trouble than it’s worth.

Comment: Use an arrow character that is filled in already. Then you can change the text's color (either the label's color or use an attributed string to set the color of the arrow).

Comment: ⏎
That arrow is just an example but ideally would like to apply to any unicode character. Will look into that @ZevEisenberg - Thanks